# Filter second dropdown from first dropdown using Jquery

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown

Team,

I have two dropdowns saying **"Years" and "Sections"**.

1) Years dropdown will be having options as **"Show All", "1", "2", "3", "4"**

2) Sections dropdown will be having options as **"All Sections", "1 Section - A", "1 Section - B", "1 Section - C", "2 Section - A", "2 Section - B", "3 Section - A", "4 Section - A", "4 Section - B"**

Now my question is, When I select **"1"** from "Years" dropdown I need to filter the options from Sections dropdown which do have **"1 Section - A", "1 Section - B", "1 Section - C"**, if selected **"2"** filter should change to **"2 Section - A", "2 Section - B"** by hiding earlier filters. When I select "All Sections", it should display all sections.

Years Dropdown:

```
<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_years" name="div_years"><option value=""> Select </option><option value="0"> All Years </option><option value="4">4</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="1">1</option></select>
```

Sections Dropdown list:

```
<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_sections" name="div_sections"><option value=""> Select </option><option value="20">1 Section - A</option><option value="21">1 Section - B</option><option value="22">1 Section - C</option><option value="24">2 Section - A</option><option value="25">2 Section - B</option><option value="28">3 Section - A</option><option value="32">4 Section - A</option><option value="33">4 Section - B</option></select>
```

I know that I need to use **.filter** but I'm not getting exact output what I need.

Hope my question is clear. Can any one please let me know how to proceed on this.

Comment: include all relevant code to OP

Comment: Years Dropdown:

<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_years" name="div_years"><option value=""> Select </option><option value="0"> All Years </option><option value="4">4</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="1">1</option></select>

Comment: Sections Dropdown list:

<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_sections" name="div_sections"><option value=""> Select </option><option value="20">1 Section - A</option><option value="21">1 Section - B</option><option value="22">1 Section - C</option><option value="24">2 Section - A</option><option value="25">2 Section - B</option><option value="28">3 Section - A</option><option value="32">4 Section - A</option><option value="33">4 Section - B</option></select>

Comment: add the code in OP not in comment

Comment: i have added it my question with the dropdown options..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind  [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change) event handler and filter based on the value using an additional `data-*` attribute.

```js
// get first dropdown and bind change event handler
$('#div_years').change(function() {
  // get optios of second dropdown and cache it
  var $options = $('#div_sections')
    // update the dropdown value if necessary
    .val('')
    // get options
    .find('option')
    // show all of the initially
    .show();
  // check current value is not 0
  if (this.value != '0')
    $options
    // filter out options which is not corresponds to the first option
    .not('[data-val="' + this.value + '"],[data-val=""]')
    // hide them
    .hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_years" name="div_years">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="0">All Years</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_sections" name="div_sections">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="20" data-val="1">1 Section - A</option>
  <option value="21" data-val="1">1 Section - B</option>
  <option value="22" data-val="1">1 Section - C</option>
  <option value="24" data-val="2">2 Section - A</option>
  <option value="25" data-val="2">2 Section - B</option>
  <option value="28" data-val="3">3 Section - A</option>
  <option value="32" data-val="4">4 Section - A</option>
  <option value="33" data-val="4">4 Section - B</option>
</select>
```

---

**UPDATE :** Or you can disable the properties using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead of hiding them.

```js
// get first dropdown and bind change event handler
$('#div_years').change(function() {
  // get optios of second dropdown and cache it
  var $options = $('#div_sections')
    // update the dropdown value if necessary
    .val('')
    // get options
    .find('option')
    // enable all options
    .prop('disabled', false);
  // check current value is not 0
  if (this.value != '0')
    $options
    // filter out options which is not corresponds to the first option
    .not('[data-val="' + this.value + '"],[data-val=""]')
    // disable options    
    .prop('disabled', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_years" name="div_years">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="0">All Years</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_sections" name="div_sections">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="20" data-val="1">1 Section - A</option>
  <option value="21" data-val="1">1 Section - B</option>
  <option value="22" data-val="1">1 Section - C</option>
  <option value="24" data-val="2">2 Section - A</option>
  <option value="25" data-val="2">2 Section - B</option>
  <option value="28" data-val="3">3 Section - A</option>
  <option value="32" data-val="4">4 Section - A</option>
  <option value="33" data-val="4">4 Section - B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @KiranKumar : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer**

Once try it, Just copy and past it..

**HTML**

Years..

```
<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_years">
    <option value=""> Select </option>
    <option value="0"> All Years </option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Sections

```
<select required="required" class="form-control" id="div_sections" >
    <option value=""> Select </option>
    <option value="20">1 Section - A</option>
    <option value="21">1 Section - B</option>
    <option value="22">1 Section - C</option>
    <option value="24">2 Section - A</option>
    <option value="25">2 Section - B</option>
    <option value="28">3 Section - A</option>
    <option value="32">4 Section - A</option>
    <option value="33">4 Section - B</option>
</select>
```

Js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#div_years").change(function () {
            var years = jQuery('#div_years').val();
            var select = jQuery('#div_sections');
            if (years == "1")
            {
                select.empty().append('<option value="20">1 Section - A</option><option value="21">1 Section - B</option><option value="22">1 Section - C</option>');
            }
            if (years == "2")
            {
                select.empty().append('<option value="24">2 Section - A</option><option value="25">2 Section - B</option>');
            }
            if (years == "3")
            {
                select.empty().append('<option value="28">3 Section - A</option>');
            }
            if (years == "4")
            {
                select.empty().append('<option value="32">4 Section - A</option><option value="33">4 Section - B</option>');
            }
            if (years == "0")
            {
                select.empty().append('<option value="20">1 Section - A</option><option value="21">1 Section - B</option><option value="22">1 Section - C</option><option value="24">2 Section - A</option><option value="25">2 Section - B</option><option value="28">3 Section - A</option><option value="32">4 Section - A</option><option value="33">4 Section - B</option>');
            }
        })
    })

</script>
```

I hope its helpful to you...