# Making an "all" data category when filtering results in second dropdown menu (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making two dropdown menus. The second menu will be filtered according to the selection in the first menu. The first will be a list of over 20 regions; the second menu will have three transportation options.

Most of the regions have only one transportation option, "car." One region is an exception and has "bike," "car" and "walk." (I tried to do an if/else but couldn't figure it out; I'm not well-versed in jQuery.) I want to have most of the regions in the same data-category, a simple "all." The problem is that I haven't been able to figure out how to create an "all" category because there's only two categories but many different values.

```
<form name="locator">

<select class="selectregion" id="regionselector" name="selectregion">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Region</option>
<option data-category="all" value="al1">Alabama: Birmingham</option>
<option data-category="all" value="al2">Alabama: Montgomery</option>
<option data-category="all" value="al3">Alabama: Tuscaloosa</option>
<option data-category="all" value="ga1">Georgia: Atlanta</option>
<option data-category="all" value="ga2">Georgia: Augusta</option>
<option data-category="bikewalk" value="ga3">Georgia: Foo</option>
</select>

<select class="vehicle" id="vehicleselector" name="selectvehicle">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Transportation</option>
<option data-value="all" value="car">Car</option>
<option data-value="bikewalk" value="bike">Bike</option>
<option data-value="bikewalk" value="walk">Walk</option>    
</select>
</form>
```

My JavaScript (customizing code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436123/filter-second-dropdown-from-first-dropdown-using-jquery):

```
$('#regionselector').change(function() { 
  var $options = $('#vehicleselector') 
    .val('') 
    .find('option') 
    .show();
  if (data-value != '0')
    $options 
    .not('[data-category="' + data-value + '"],[data-category=""]')
    .hide();
});
```

I replaced this.value with data-value and unsurprisingly it didn't work. Right now, nothing filters down.

What can I do to show "car" for every region and "car," "bike," and "walk" for the one exception?  (Foo, Georgia in this example). Thank you for your help.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aprilin30/vgqznma2/)

**UPDATE:** [The post suggested as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579532/show-hide-select-options-based-on-previous-selection-dropdown-in-jquery-or-javas) – where classes are used instead of data-categories – solved the problem. Combining that code with mine, just use "all" and "bikewalk" as classes for Foo (the region with all three vehicle options) and "all" as the single class on the rest. Then *bike/car/walk* are the options on Foo and *car* is the option for the other regions.

Comment: You want select value in #regionselector and filter options in select #vehicleselector?

Answer (score 0):

You can think in reversed approach. All options are hidden and on select action show right options.

```
$('#regionselector').change(function() {
    // always on change hide all options
    $('#vehicleselector option').not('[value=""]').hide();

    // get selected value from #regionselector
    let option = $(this).find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');

    // get value start with 2 chars
    let value = option.val().substring(0,2);

    // get all options start with value
    let optionsStartWithValue = $(this).find('option[value^="' + value + '"]');

    // for each options for region show vehicle
    optionsStartWithValue.each(function(i, v) {
      // show all options in #vehicleselector which contain selected data category
      $('#vehicleselector option[data-value="' + $(v).data('category') + '"]').show();
    });
});

// reset values
$('#vehicleselector').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
    $('#regionselector').val('');
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vgqznma2/48/)

Comment: Pretty good, but you're missing an auto-update back to "select" when it's changed. If I select car, then change to a location where cars don't work, it stays car until I reselect.

Comment: You need bidirectional selection? region->vehicle  vehicle->region?

Comment: No. Just setting transportation mode back to "select a transportation" when the location is changed, because otherwise it will stay on something else even if that isn't allowed.

Comment: @daremachine Thank you so much for your help so far. The only thing that's missing is "car" under Foo, Georgia. That region has all three options ("car," "bike," and "walk"). The other cities just have "car." (Also, I don't need bidirectional selection, for the record. Just region -> vehicle.)

Comment: so if I select gorgia so all tags (all, bikewalk) show all things? It does not make sense because category is different. You need to show selected tags and also 'all' tag?

Comment: This is what you need I think.

Comment: @daremachine My apologies, I realize now that naming the first category "all" was confusing. "All" is meant to represent vehicle options that are common to all listed regions (in this case, just the car). Five of the six regions in my example are car-only. "Foo" is the only region that offers car, bike, and walk. Does that make more sense? Thanks again.

Comment: My updated code do this. Sorry I don't understand what you really want.

Comment: @daremachine No need to say sorry, I'm really grateful that you volunteered your time to help me out! Thank you so much.